# Select distinct rows from a datatable with criteria involving multiple columns using LINQ with VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a datatable as shown in the figure.

[image: Initail table]

Let me explain my required based on this image. I have 7 rows of data. The rows 1 and 2 contains columns till `UnitSqcNo` same. I want only row 3 among the two. In general I want select all the rows with distinct `model, unittype, unit` and rest with greater `CompId`. ie the table should look like

[image: Resultant table]

Comment: For Each dr As DataRow In dtCompDetails.Rows
                    Dim dtDistinctRows = From dRow In dtCompDetails.Rows _
                                         Where dRow("OrgModelId") = dr("OrgModelID") _
                                         And dRow("OrgUnitTypeID") = dr("OrgUnitTypeID") _
                                         And dRow("OrgUnitID") = dr("OrgUnitID") _
                                         Select dRow.Distinct()
                Next

Comment: Don't you have any primary key in this table ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have no experience in VB.Net, so I post in C#:

It seems you want to filter out double entries of UnitName and keep only those with the highest value of CompID. Given that, you could try the following:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTable(); //your logic of building your data table

//order rows by CompID, group by UnitName and keep only first entry of each group        
var filteredData = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() orderby row.Field<int>("CompID") descending group row by row.Field<string>("UnitName")).Select(r => r.First());

DataTable nt = GetDataTable(); //alternatively, you could build a new data table
nt.Rows.Clear();  //clear table as it is used as destination for filtered data

foreach (DataRow r in filteredData)  //add filtered rows to table
{
     DataRow n = nt.NewRow();
     n.ItemArray = r.ItemArray;
      nt.Rows.Add(n);
}
```